# TypeError: argument must be sequence of values

Tags: cursor, arcpy

I am using an insert cursor to put all of the values for the field "Size" into all of the rows in my dbf.  Here is the code that I am using:

```
for i in range(0,144779):
    cursor2=arcpy.da.InsertCursor("Distance_Table.dbf",["Size"])
    cursor2.insertRow(1)

#Delete cursor object
del cursor2
```

I know that the last record in the table was 144,779.  I put it into the range statement to see whether the value of the variable I had calculated was causing the error and it was not.  I keep getting this message "TypeError:  argument must be sequence of values."  I am putting the same size value in all and I will use an update cursor to update the values.

Comment: This would be better asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the cursor first, then iterate over your range of values. Here, you create a new cursor for each iteration.

Also, the row object you insert is a tuple and it should be enclosed with round brackets, even if there is only 1 field:

```
cursor2 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("Distance_Table.dbf",["Size"])
for i in range(0,144779):
    cursor2.insertRow((1))

#Delete cursor object
del cursor2
```